# Slot Machine game with asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to build a simple slot machine game with asynctask. I have the following code.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="146sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNum2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="146sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNum3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="146sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btStartStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start/Stop"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.android.iqbal.slotmachine;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btStartStop;
    private TextView tvNum;
    private TextView tvNum2;
    private TextView tvNum3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.tvNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNum);
        this.tvNum2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNum2);
        this.tvNum3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNum3);
        this.btStartStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStartStop);

        this.btStartStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    RandomTask randomTask, randomTask2, randomTask3;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if (randomTask == null || randomTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            randomTask = new RandomTask(this.tvNum);
            randomTask.execute();
        } else {
            randomTask.cancel(true);
        }
        if (randomTask2 == null || randomTask2.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            randomTask2 = new RandomTask(this.tvNum2);
            randomTask2.execute();
        } else {
            randomTask2.cancel(true);
        }
        if (randomTask3 == null || randomTask3.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
            randomTask3 = new RandomTask(this.tvNum3);
            randomTask3.execute();
        } else {
            randomTask3.cancel(true);
        }

    }
}
```

RandomTask

```
package com.android.iqbal.slotmachine;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RandomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

private TextView tvNum;
private int mNum;

public RandomTask(TextView tvNum){
    this.tvNum = tvNum;
}
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        while (true) {
            mNum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            publishProgress(mNum);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return mNum;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    mNum = values[0];
    this.tvNum.setText(mNum + "");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);
    this.tvNum.setText(mNum + "");
}
}
```

What I'm aiming to do is to random all three textview when I click start. And then stopping one text view at a time everytime I hit stop. But the problem is with this code, only the first text view is being shuffled. How do I shuffle all three textview and stop them one by one?

Comment: By seeing the last code you are just updating the text of one of the textview.

Comment: Just a general comment, ditch the AsyncTasks and use Animators or post Runnables on a Handler instead. This is not something that has to be done on background thread

Comment: @patrick-iv how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok , here is the answer, I did some changes in your code, it is easy to understand:

```
public class RandomTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

private TextView tvNumReference;
private int mNum;
private boolean isRunning;

public RandomTask(TextView tvNum){
    this.tvNumReference = tvNum;
    isRunning = true;
}
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        while (isRunning) {
            mNum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            publishProgress(mNum);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return mNum;
}


 public boolean isRunning(){
      return isRunning;
    }
public void stop(){
    isRunning = false;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    mNum = values[0];
    this.tvNumReference.setText(mNum + "");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);
    this.tvNumReference.setText(mNum + "");
}
}
```

Here is you onclick method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (randomTask == null || !randomTask.isRunning()){
            randomTask = new RandomTask(this.tvNum);
            randomTask.execute();
        } else {
            randomTask.stop();
        }

        if (randomTask2 == null || !randomTask2.isRunning()){
            randomTask2 = new RandomTask(this.tvNum2);
            randomTask2.execute();
        } else {
            randomTask2.stop();
        }

        if (randomTask3 == null || !randomTask3.isRunning()){
            randomTask3 = new RandomTask(this.tvNum3);
            randomTask3.execute();
        } else {
            randomTask3.stop();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it doesnt shuffle the other 2 textviews, and when I hit stop, the other 2 textviews values change to 0

Comment: I updated my answer, I change the name of the variable in the asynctask , now is tvNumReference to avoid conflicts with your tvNum variable in your activity

Comment: could you update the code in your answer? I want to check if it is correct